# iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded

Tags: ubuntu

Well, I have my Ubuntu VPS here, and when I try to open ports using iptables, it gives the following error:

```
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': 
Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I have already updated iptables and the kernel and it still has not resolved. I changed iptables to version 1.8.x, and still it was no use.

Attempting to execute the command:

```
iptables -F; iptables -X
```

And the command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
```

(Trying to open ports to run a SAMP server)

All commands involving ports in iptables give this error.

Comment: This isn't in a Dockerfile, is it?

Comment: @Drakes I have the same error when trying to do sth like `RUN iptables -L` inside my Dockerfile during build. What is the problem with that?